# Impossible to create thrust::host_vector of cusp::coo_matrix within device_memory?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, nvcc, cusp-library

I am trying to make a vector of `cusp::coo_matrix` and it seems one cannot use `thrust::host_vector` in this manner. Consider this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    typedef typename cusp::coo_matrix<int, float, cusp::device_memory> maintype;
    maintype B;
    thrust::host_vector<maintype> h_vec(2,B);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error message from `nvcc`:

```
Warning: calling a __host__ function("thrust::detail::vector_base<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int> > ::vector_base") from a __host__ __device__ function("thrust::detail::vector_base<int, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int> > ::vector_base [subobject]") is not allowed

Warning: calling a __host__ function("thrust::detail::vector_base<float, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<float> > ::vector_base") from a __host__ __device__ function("thrust::detail::vector_base<float, thrust::device_malloc_allocator<float> > ::vector_base [subobject]") is not allowed
```

The interesting thing is I get the exact same errors with `cusp::host_memory` instead (well, almost the same):

```
Warning: calling a __host__ function("thrust::detail::vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> > ::vector_base") from a __host__ __device__ function("thrust::detail::vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> > ::vector_base [subobject]") is not allowed

Warning: calling a __host__ function("thrust::detail::vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> > ::vector_base") from a __host__ __device__ function("thrust::detail::vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> > ::vector_base [subobject]") is not allowed
```

So, my question is, is it really a drawback or am I doing something wrong? Any help much appreciated.

In addition, I've tested `std::vector` instead of `thrust::host_vector` and it works fine. Not that I am such a big fan of Thrust library, but I'm just curious. Moreover, I will need to rewrite a bit of code in case `thrust::host_vector` isn't suitable (`thrust::find` and some other functions are used).

Also, are there any other ways of making an array of cusp matrices? I don't think raw pointers and `new/delete` is anyhow better than `std::vector`, am I right?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you, seems you are spot on. Cusp is indeed built on thrust (well, at least, in my case `cusp::coo_matrix` is), so it makes perfect sense why it didn't want to work. But it is still rather weird, isn't it?

Comment: It ought to work; the warnings are benign.

Comment: Okay, thank you, @JaredHoberock , I will pay no attention to such type of warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As identified in comments, the compiler warnings are benign. It is safe to use not POD types in thrust host vectors. It would not be safe to do the same thing with a thrust device vector.

*This answer was added as a community wiki from comments to get it off the unanswered list*